# Problem when i try to sort using lamda expresion in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have to order  by discovery date an Artefact and print the content .

I have this class :

```
class Artifact{
protected:
    int discoveryDate_;
    int estimatedDateOfOrigin_;
    Artifact::artifactType _artifactType;
    Artifact::condition_ _condition;
};
```

I also have 2 derived class GreekArtifact and Egypteam artifact and i created 5 object of GreekArtifact and 5 objects of Egypteam artifact and i added them in a list

```
std::list<Artifact> artifacts;
```

And i tried to sort this list by discovery date and i did this :

```
 std::sort(artifacts.begin(),artifacts.end(),[](auto &a, auto &b){
        return a->getDiscoveryDate() > b->getDiscoveryDate();
   });
```

and this sort doesnt work and i dont know why and i really dont understand the error that sounds like this :

```
error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<Artifact>' and 'std::_List_iterator<Artifact>')
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
```

Can you please help me to figure out what i did wrong??

Comment: `std::sort` is incompatible with `std::list`. Either use another (random access) container like `std::vector`, or `std::list::sort()` member function.

Comment: @sdfjhsbfjskfck What is this     Artifact::artifactType _artifactType;
    Artifact::condition_ _condition;?

Comment: @sdfjhsbfjskfck The class template std::list has its own ,method sort.

Comment: It worked and i did like this ```artifacts.sort([](auto &a, auto &b){
        return a.getDiscoveryDate() < b.getDiscoveryDate();
   });``` Thank you Evg